# Auto switch customer group in magento

Tags: php, magento

Has anyone found a way to auto switch a customer group based on specific rules? For example, if a customer over their lifetime has ordered 200 plus bottles of something they are grouped in a specific customer tier and get special pricing (wholesale type situation)

I know how to do segments of customers but that doesn't help me auto change which customer group they belong too.

Thanks in advance for any help in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of payable extensions at [magento connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/group-change-5742.html) or you can create simple module with custom actions. [Article](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/automatically-set-magento-customer-group) for a good start.

Comment: That article is very good, but if you want to listen for more actions (perhaps `checkout_submit_all_after`), this page should help you out. http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/

Comment: I have a few ideas I am working on, will post my solution when i figured out how I am going to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for an answer, this extension (which I created) can do exactly what you are looking for and more out of the box:

Website:

https://plugin.company/magento-extensions/automatic-customer-group-switching.html

On Magento Connect:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/automatic-customer-group-switching-by-plugin-company.html

If you'd like to build your own custom functionality though, I'd recommend looking into the `sales_order_placed_after` event and getting the order history details by filtering an order collection on the customer ID that has placed the order.

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $yourCustomerId);
```

You can then loop through each order and get all items by using the `getAllItems`method.

Alternatively you could retrieve a `sales_order_item` collection, and join the corresponding order details from the `sales_flat_order` table. Then you could filter on customer ID and product ID and group the results on product ID.

You can then base your customer group switching logic on the sum of the total ordered product quantity.